# Premade drop down select with all languages

Tags: html, list, select, lang

This is not a technical question.

I just can't find what i am really looking for : a premade  list of all spoken languages (Preferably in french).

Kinda like this : http://snipplr.com/view/4794/50-most-common-languages-spoken-in-the-united-states--drop-down-list-for-an-online-form/

But the one above is incomplete and it's in english :/

Maybe one of you knows where i could find something like this. It would be terribly long to do and my guess is that this was already made at least a thousand times. (Any distro, any international websites...)

I have tried googling it but i get no accurate results. (it's a little pointy)

I am sorry if this is out of context or shouldn't be asked here. If that is the case, feel free to do what you must.

Many thanks!

Comment: strange question.. but here has good lists : https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list/tree/master/country/cldr

Comment: also the standard is here: http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php You could write a parse script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where this question DOES belong but the best resource I can find actually : [ISO 639.2](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)

Codes arranged alphabetically by alpha-3/ISO 639-2 Code

Contains the French translation for all Languages provided.

Im not sure you will get a more concise list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the site with what you (I am sure-  not you alone) were looking for:
http://www.freeformatter.com/iso-country-list-html-select.html

and this is the list of languages "borrowed "from Google Translate:

```
  <select>  
    <option value=af>Afrikaans</option>
    <option value=sq>Albanian</option>
    <option value=am>Amharic</option>
    <option value=ar>Arabic</option>
    <option value=hy>Armenian</option>
    <option value=az>Azerbaijani</option>
    <option value=eu>Basque</option>
    <option value=be>Belarusian</option>
    <option value=bn>Bengali</option>
    <option value=bs>Bosnian</option>
    <option value=bg>Bulgarian</option>
    <option value=ca>Catalan</option>
    <option value=ceb>Cebuano</option>
    <option value=ny>Chichewa</option>
    <option value=zh-CN>Chinese</option>
    <option value=co>Corsican</option>
    <option value=hr>Croatian</option>
    <option value=cs>Czech</option>
    <option value=da>Danish</option>
    <option value=nl>Dutch</option>
    <option value=en>English</option>
    <option value=eo>Esperanto</option>
    <option value=et>Estonian</option>
    <option value=tl>Filipino</option>
    <option value=fi>Finnish</option>
    <option value=fr>French</option>
    <option value=fy>Frisian</option>
    <option value=gl>Galician</option>
    <option value=ka>Georgian</option>
    <option value=de>German</option>
    <option value=el>Greek</option>
    <option value=gu>Gujarati</option>
    <option value=ht>Haitian Creole</option>
    <option value=ha>Hausa</option>
    <option value=haw>Hawaiian</option>
    <option value=iw>Hebrew</option>
    <option value=hi>Hindi</option>
    <option value=hmn>Hmong</option>
    <option value=hu>Hungarian</option>
    <option value=is>Icelandic</option>
    <option value=ig>Igbo</option>
    <option value=id>Indonesian</option>
    <option value=ga>Irish</option>
    <option value=it>Italian</option>
    <option value=ja>Japanese</option>
    <option value=jw>Javanese</option>
    <option value=kn>Kannada</option>
    <option value=kk>Kazakh</option>
    <option value=km>Khmer</option>
    <option value=ko>Korean</option>
    <option value=ku>Kurdish (Kurmanji)</option>
    <option value=ky>Kyrgyz</option>
    <option value=lo>Lao</option>
    <option value=la>Latin</option>
    <option value=lv>Latvian</option>
    <option value=lt>Lithuanian</option>
    <option value=lb>Luxembourgish</option>
    <option value=mk>Macedonian</option>
    <option value=mg>Malagasy</option>
    <option value=ms>Malay</option>
    <option value=ml>Malayalam</option>
    <option value=mt>Maltese</option>
    <option value=mi>Maori</option>
    <option value=mr>Marathi</option>
    <option value=mn>Mongolian</option>
    <option value=my>Myanmar (Burmese)</option>
    <option value=ne>Nepali</option>
    <option value=no>Norwegian</option>
    <option value=ps>Pashto</option>
    <option value=fa>Persian</option>
    <option value=pl>Polish</option>
    <option value=pt>Portuguese</option>
    <option value=pa>Punjabi</option>
    <option value=ro>Romanian</option>
    <option value=ru>Russian</option>
    <option value=sm>Samoan</option>
    <option value=gd>Scots Gaelic</option>
    <option value=sr>Serbian</option>
    <option value=st>Sesotho</option>
    <option value=sn>Shona</option>
    <option value=sd>Sindhi</option>
    <option value=si>Sinhala</option>
    <option value=sk>Slovak</option>
    <option value=sl>Slovenian</option>
    <option value=so>Somali</option>
    <option value=es>Spanish</option>
    <option value=su>Sundanese</option>
    <option value=sw>Swahili</option>
    <option value=sv>Swedish</option>
    <option value=tg>Tajik</option>
    <option value=ta>Tamil</option>
    <option value=te>Telugu</option>
    <option value=th>Thai</option>
    <option value=tr>Turkish</option>
    <option value=uk>Ukrainian</option>
    <option value=ur>Urdu</option>
    <option value=uz>Uzbek</option>
    <option value=vi>Vietnamese</option>
    <option value=cy>Welsh</option>
    <option value=xh>Xhosa</option>
    <option value=yi>Yiddish</option>
    <option value=yo>Yoruba</option>
    <option value=zu>Zulu</option>
    </select>
```